Error: "The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY"
[sudo] password for huzaifa: 
Hit:1 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease               
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease                         
Get:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease [3,594 B]   
Err:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
E: The repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

